# svn backup repository

Tags: svn

I managed to bring down my subversion remote server (temporarily).
However, I have a file backup with subversion root.

is it possible to temporarily update working copy from this backup root, while maintaining/(or reverting) original repository location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it's best (if you're copying from a live server) to use `svnadmin hotcopy` instead of a plain fil copy; this ensures that things get read in an order that avoids race conditions if someone commits during the copy. But if you copied from a server that nobody was using at the time a file copy is fine.

To change what server a working copy pulls from, use `svn switch --relocate [URL]` to change how it accesses the repository. Then, when your server is back, just use it again to change back.